# Java Application/Class Design - How do accessors in Java work?

Tags: java

How do I write the getDB() function and use it properly?

Here is a code snippet of my App Object:

```
public class MyApp extends UiApplication {

    private static PersistentObject m_oStore;
    private static MyBigObjectOfStorage m_oDB;

    static {
        store = PersistentStore.getPersistentObject(0xa1a569278238dad2L);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyApp theApp = new MyApp();
        theApp.enterEventDispatcher();
    }
    public MyApp() {
        pushScreen(new MyMainScreen());
    }

    // Is this correct?  Will it return a copy of m_oDB or a reference of m_oDB?
    public MyBigObjectOfStorage getDB() {
        return m_oDB;  // returns a reference
    }

}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with the object from getDB()? To question your comment regarding getDB(), it will return a reference of m_oDB, in if that is all your code there is..it will return null, because m_oDB is not initialized yet. To use it properly, it depends on your intention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public MyBigObjectOfStorage getDB() {
  return m_oDB;
}
```

As you put it is correct. It will return a *copy of the reference*, which is kind of in between a copy and a reference.

The actual object instance returned by getDB() is the same object referenced by m_oDB. However, you can't change the reference returned by getDB() to point at a different object and have it actually cause the local private m_oDB to point at the new object. m_oDB will still point at the object it was already.

See http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2000-05/03-qa-0526-pass.html for more detail.

Although looking through your code there, you never set m_oDB at all, so getDB() will always return null.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for.  Thanks much.  I'll set m_oDB.  :-)  I'm experienced but not with Java (yet).

Answer (score 0):

```
public MyBigObjectOfStorage getDB() {
    Object o = store.getContents();
    if ( o instanceof MyBigObjectOfStorage ) {
        return (MyBigObjectOfStorage) o;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Very helpful but not exactly what I was looking for.  Shouldn't I put the value returned by store.getContents() in a member variable of the application so that "getContents()" doesn't have to be called for every access?

Answer (score 0):

I am one of those folks that are very much against using singletons and/or statics as it tends to make unit testing impossible. As this is posted under best practices, I suggest that you take a look at using a dependency injection framework. Personally I am using and prefer [Google Guice](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/).